# Python consumes all RAM, process killed

Tags: python, ram, garbage

I'm running Linux Mint via VirtualBox, and the Python code I'm using contains an iteration over a large data set to produce plots. The first couple of times I tried to run it, part way through the process it stopped with a message simple saying "Killed".

A bit of research showed that this is most likely due to a lack of RAM for the process. When repeating the process and monitoring the system resource usage (using command top -s), and sure enough I can watch the ram usage going up at a fairly constant rate as the program runs. I'm giving the VirtualBox all the RAM my system can afford (just over 2Gb), but it doesn't seem to be enough for the iterations I'm doing. The code looks like this:

```
  for file in os.listdir('folder/'):
      calledfunction('folder/'+file, 'output/'+file)
```

The calledfunction produces a png image, so it takes about 50mb of RAM per iteration and I want to do it about 40 times.

So, my question is, can I use a function to prevent the build up of RAM usage, or clear the RAM after each iteration? I've seen people talking garbage collection but I'm not really sure how to use it, or where I can/should put it in my loop. Any protips?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with the PNG? Are you keeping a reference to it, or are you writing it to file? If you are sure you are _not_ keeping a reference, and RAM still builds up, a workaround might be to rewrite your program to create only one PNG and then write a second program (python, or a shell script) calling your first program 40 times.

Comment: There is a manual garbage collection feature in CPython (```gc.collect()```), but usually this is handled by the implementation of CPython and there is no need to interfere with that. Did you close the file after writing to it? What does ```calledfunction``` look like? (BTW: I think the RAM is not freed instantaneously, but released after some time)

Comment: Can you show some code of `calledfunction `

Comment: The calledfunction is basically a plotting function which takes information from a .fits file, plots it, then saves it as a .png for later referencing (i.e. so I can view the outputs once the code has done it for all files). The .png is not displayed at the completion of each iteration. Once it's plotted and the .png file is created it should be fine to remove it from the memory as I won't be calling it again. Haven't tried closing the file, but I don't think that should be an issue. Trouble is I didn't actually write the function so I'm not perfectly clear on how it works.